# R package documentation

Tags: r, latex, r-package

I am writing my first R package. How can I use Latex to type math symbols in description file? Thank you

```
#'Iteratively solves the convex 
#'optimization problem using ADMM.
#'
#'       min     |X|_* + gamma* |Y|_1 + 1_Omega_W (W) + 1_Omega_Q (Q)+ 1_Omega_Z (Z)
#'       s.t      X - Y = 0
#'               X = W
#'               X = Z
```

Comment: Are you referring to the `DESCRIPTION` at the top level of the package? I do not know any official way. Do you have seen a package where this is done?

Comment: @RalfStubner, I have attached a part of this description. BTW, it is located in actual R file before function

Comment: Still not entirely clear what you mean. If this is part of roxygen-style documentation that will end up in a `.Rd` file when you build the package (i.e. run `devtools::document()` or `roxygen2::roxygenize`), see https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Mathematics

Comment: I think you are being loose with your descriptors, which is causing confusion. (Or maybe I'm wrong?) Every R package must have a file named `DESCRIPTION` at the top level of the package, which contains author and license info as well as a description of the package. The file is a text file with no extension and is typically *not parsed*. Is it this `DESCRIPTION` file you are talking about when you write *"description file"*? Or do you mean an Rdocumentation file for a particular function/help page? Perhaps the Description *section* of said help page? And you are using Roxygen?

Comment: If you mean an Rd (R documentation) help file, I would suggest editing your question to not use the term "description file".